# SELECT list incompatible with DISTINCT with alias and order by

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables (MySQL 8, SQLAlchemy 1.4):

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    id BIGINT auto_increment NOT NULL,
    offset BIGINT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
INSERT INTO user (offset) values (1);
INSERT INTO user (offset) values (2);
INSERT INTO user (offset) values (3);
INSERT INTO user (offset) values (4);


CREATE TABLE score (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    score BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT score_FK FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
)

INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (1, 10);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (1, 9);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (1, 8);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (2, 7);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (2, 6);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (2, 5);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (3, 10);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (3, 9);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (3, 8);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (4, 7);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (4, 6);
INSERT INTO score (user_id, score) values (4, 5);
```

I want to write a sqlalchemy query the translates to this SQL (the following code is a very simplified version of the actual query):

```sql
select distinct
    id,
    max(score) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max_score,
    offset
from
    user
left join score on id = user_id
order by max_score + offset
```

Expected output :

```
| id | score | offset |
| -- | ----- | ------ |
|   3|     10|       3|
|   1|     10|       1|
|   4|      7|       4|
|   2|      7|       2|
```

I tried using the `over` clause both in the `select` and the `order by` and I tried defining an element to reuse it, as follows :

```py
max_score = func.max(Score.score).over(partition_by=User.id).label("max_score")

q = (
    session.query(
        User.id,
        User.offset,
        max_score,
    )
    .outerjoin(Score)
    .order_by((max_score + User.offset).desc())
).distinct().all()
```

Both methods produce the error "SELECT list incompatible with DISTINCT" because in the generated SQL, the order by clause uses the definition of `max_score` and not the "alias" :

```sql
ORDER BY
    max(score.score) OVER (PARTITION BY user.id) + user.offset DESC
```

In the generated SQL, if I replace the previous clause by :

```sql
ORDER BY
   max_score + user.offset DESC
```

it works as expected.

The error comes from Mysql I know, but how can I write my query so that SQLAlchemy uses the alias.

Note: tried with `aliased` also, didn't work.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Sample data and expected output added.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually have a version working with a subquery, but I'm trying to get rid of it because the score table is getting big (~1M rows). From the explain plans and preliminary tests the over partition by seems to perform better.

Comment: Works for me without error (SQLA v2.0.19).

Comment: Good to know. I started migrating my code to 2.0 but, sadly i'm stuck with 1.4 for now.